# Node.js sending binary data of HTTP over a socket

Tags: http, node.js

I am writing my own http module (I know that node.js includes one)
I am using the net module
when I am getting a request for a static binary(picture) file, how do I generate HTTP response with the binary file? 
When I do exactly that for text file(e.g. html file) it just works..

Comment: Can I ask why you are writing it yourself? You'll need to write a parser for HTTP requests, and then make sure that your responses have the proper headers. Could you post the code you have? What exactly fails when you request the image? How are you sending test requests?

Comment: it's for learning purpose...I had wrote an HTTP/1.1 parser, when I send am html file it works, when I send an image it doesn't show..(I send the correct content-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the net module, you are probably using a code such as :

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) { 
});
```

What is a socket? it represents the stream of data over the network.
In objects, Socket is a WriteableStream, read more here: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/streams.html

When you are reading a file you can get the content as String, Buffer or as a ReadableStream

The easiest way to read file as a stream is by using the function: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/fs.html#fs.createReadStream
e.g.

```
var fileAsAstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
```

In order to transfer the content of a binary read-stream to a write-stream you can use the pipe function http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/streams.html#stream.pipe functions
e.g.

```
fileAsAstream.pipe(socket);
```